# usage of radio button for asp server in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code for asp server in javascript. I need to add an IF condition at the end so that it adds in the responce a "mr." if they check the male gender radio button and "miss." if check female radio button. Right in front of the name they submit. It seems pretty simple but i cant find the right syntax for it.

```html
<%@ LANGUAGE="Javascript" %>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
        <TITLE>Main Page</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY TopMargin="0" Leftmargin="0">
        <form action="./ask.asp" method="post">
            Student name: <input type="text" name="name" size="20"><br><br>

            Sex:
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Male" id="choice-Male">
            <label for="choice-Male">Male</label><br>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Female" id="choice-Female">
            <label for="choice-Female">Female</label><br><br>       
            
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
        </form>

        <%
            Response.Write("Thanks " + Request.Form("name"))
        %>      
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use

```html
var genderChoice=Request.form("choice")
```